# code igniter return strings, arrays, .etc from module to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codigniter and I have a general question. From sample code I have learned that model are reserved for functions that basically return bool, what if, however, I wanted to return a string or array to the controller calling the model functions? So for example if I have a function in `Model A` that checks for `foo == bar` and then returns 'yes' as a string or `no`... how do I access that in the controller?

```
$this->load->module('a');
if ($this->a->function == 'yes') {
   echo 'yes';
}
```

According to my previous php knowledge the above should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: this should work fine ... do a var_dump and see the result  ... modules are not reserved for anything ! you can do whatever you want with them ... but generally they are used for databse layer codes

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post a link to the sample code - there is no such thing as the code you've posted in Codeigniter

Codeigniter does have a well-known extension called HMVC that uses modules, but it has nothing to do with what you are describing

Comment: how is there no such thing as what i described? i described a module, and a contoller... codeigniter is mvc... perhaps you could elaborate

Comment: there's no such thing in the framework. Perhaps you are thinking of models?

Comment: actually your definition above is wrong. you prolly want to look at user guide some more